# SQLite One-to-Many how can i get foreign key object?

Tags: android, sqlite, one-to-many

For example I've got a table "phones" with foreign key to "user" table. How can I get list of phones for same user where phone.user field will be same object for each phone?

```
public class User{
    int id;
    String name;
}

public class Phone{
    int id;
    User user;
    String number;
}

╔═════════╦══════╗
║ USER_ID ║ NAME ║
╠═════════╬══════╣ 
║       1 ║ User ║
║       2 ║ Man  ║
║       3 ║ Dog  ║
╚═════════╩══════╝

╔═══════════╦═════════════╦════════╗
║ PHONE_ID  ║ USER_ID_FK  ║ NUMBER ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬════════╣
║         1 ║           1 ║    000 ║
║         2 ║           1 ║    001 ║
║         3 ║           3 ║    002 ║
║         4 ║           1 ║    003 ║
║         5 ║           3 ║    004 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩════════╝
```

When I query:

> SELECT * FROM PHONES

Takes USER_ID_FK from cursor, then goes to USERS table:

> SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = USER_ID_FK

Each time I got a row from USERS it creates new User object.

Ok, it is logical.

But I want to know if there is the way to map same foreign key to same object? I guess the ORM is way to solve it (because in Java EE ORM handles this with annotations). But does native Android Framework instruments can help me to reach  this?

P.S. I know that can simplify query using JOIN, but I tried make problem clearly.

Comment: You seem confused. If you don't have a particular `USER_ID` then how do you select which `USER_ID` to take. If all of them then why not simply `SELECT *` from `User` Table. Should be a lot easier. Unless you only want `Users` who have atleast one phone?

Comment: @Abbas I want get all Phones maped to java object List<Phone> where for each phone with same USER_ID_FK it will be same User object in Java. For example Phones[1].user.equals(Phones[2].user) will return true; The problem is cursor to object always returns new Object. I can try handle it on class level, but tries to find easier way If Android provides such.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem completely. But if you are saying a new User object is created for each Phone (because when you query you create a new `User` object) then you could `Override` `equals()` method of User and provide your own implementation. If this is what you mean by *handling it on class' level* then AFAIK Android does not provide any method to compare your custom class' member variables.

Comment: However you could read all your `User`s add them to a list. *and then* you could read `Phones` and pass `User` object that matches from the `usersList`. If you do, you can simply use `==` operator to check if the `currentPhoen.user` `newPhone.user` are infact the same objects.

Comment: @Abbas Yeah, I thought there is some hidden mechanism (annotations, or some wrappers) for that based on Foreign key references, like: Android - Oh, that guy wants me to give him object from foreign key, but I alredy did that before for this key, I'll give him that object instead of creating new one :D Hoped on that beacuse worked with ORM in Java EE, it seems rather logical.